MySQL Net Connector v9.1 crashes program when calling async functions when connection to database fails
I am writing a WPF application that communicates with MySQL database and have run into an unrecoverable error when trying to call async functions from MySQL if the program is not able to connect to the server. Even if the call is wrapped in a try/catch block to handle the error the program will crash completely.
The current environment setup is MySQL Net Connector version 9.1 with .Net Framework version 4.7.2 on Windows 10.
I have tested the same program using the synchronous methods and it works as expected.  If there is no connection then the method will throw a MySqlException: Timeout expired which gets caught and the program continues.
Below is a simple example that will crash the program without the ability to handle the exception.
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);

    try
    {
        await conn.OpenAsync();  // <---- Code crashes on this line
        Console.WriteLine("Connection Sucess!");
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connection Failure!");
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}

The error messages are as follows:
System.AggregateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=One or more errors occurred.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.ExecuteCallbackHandlers(Boolean throwOnFirstException) in System.Threading\CancellationTokenSource.cs:line 445
   at System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.NotifyCancellation(Boolean throwOnFirstException) in System.Threading\CancellationTokenSource.cs:line 376
   at System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.TimerCallbackLogic(Object obj) in System.Threading\CancellationTokenSource.cs:line 243
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallbackInContext(Object state) in System.Threading\TimerQueueTimer.cs:line 207
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) in System.Threading\ExecutionContext.cs:line 515
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) in System.Threading\ExecutionContext.cs:line 486
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback() in System.Threading\TimerQueueTimer.cs:line 200
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire() in System.Threading\TimerQueueTimer.cs:line 158
   at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers() in System.Threading\TimerQueue.cs:line 252
   at System.Threading.TimerQueue.AppDomainTimerCallback(Int32 id) in System.Threading\TimerQueue.cs:line 114

Inner Exception 1:
MySqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Inner Exception 2:
TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.

I have also tried other versions of MySQL Net Connector such as 8.4 and 8.0.33 with no success. I was previously working with version 8.0.31 and errors on async methods would be handled in the try/catch with no issue, although my understanding is that version was not actually asynchronous.

What error message do you get when the program crashes? Copy/Paste it to your question

Did you try stepping through? Which line crashes, executing the conn.OpenAsync and then it bails out without going to the catch?

Did you set the timeout as Hans recommended by closing this question? If not we'll try and re-open.

Increasing the connection timeout to 60 does work and allows the program to enter the catch block without a fatal crash of the program.  Thank you!  This does seem like a bug in the MySQL Connector.

As I know Oracle's MySQL Net Connector do not support real async operations and just emulates them and actually has a lot of bugs. Try MySqlConnector instead.
